# Как сделать грамотное сохранение

Tags: unity3d

У меня в игре должно быть сохранение. Я знаю, что есть такая штука как playerprefs, но она позволяет хранить только переменные. У меня генерация деревьев и прочего через скрипт, и при каждом запуске сцены они разные. Неужели, мне нужно будет все объекты сохранять через массивы, чтобы записать положение всех объектов на сцене? Если есть какой нибудь другой путь для сохранения, скажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Знаю идея бредовая: создавать рядом с игрой фалы.txt записавать туда значения которые нужно сохранить, потом их шифровать и менять разрешенее на допусти файл.gg. Все это не сложно реализовать C# испольховав библиотеку System.IO; Подробнее про работу с файлами - https://goo.gl/AQAjVu . Вопрос хороший

Comment: А как насчет стартовых значений для генераций ? Ну т.е. раз генерируются деревья, то сделайте стартовое значение известным. И именно его записывать в сэйв. Тогда после загрузки ваш алгоритм для известного стартового значения будет всегда рисовать одну и ту же сцену. Правда тут придется задействовать алгоритмы и математику для того, чтобы для конечного n всегда существовало только единичное значение y (х - стартовое число, y - результат генерации).

Comment: pavel1787mego, не такая уж и бредовая, наверное так и сделаю у себя ;)

Answer (score 2):

В Unity есть не только **PlayerPrefs**, но еще **BinarySerialization** - который как раз годится для хранения более сложных объектов чем **PlayerPrefs**, и также есть **[JSON Serialization](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html)** - который использует класс **[JSONUtility](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html)** и позволяет хранить данные JSON формата.

В вашем случае я бы сохранял все в JSON файл.